# VBScript kills program before text file is made

Tags: python, excel, vbscript

I made a vbscript to open an excel doc, then runs a python program that pulls data from the documents tables and prints it to a text file. The script is supposed to wait until the python program is done creating the text doc then close the excel doc, but for whatever reason my python program closes before it even has a chance to make that text doc.

I even changed the python code to just print a simple 'Hello World' into a new text document in case pulling data from excel was causing problems but the text document still wasn't created.

This is the script that i'm running:

```
 Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.application")

 xl.Application.Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\V\Documents\_PROGRAMS_\TEST.xlsx"
 xl.Application.Visible = True

 Dim oshell
 Set oshell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

 oshell.CurrentDirectory = "C:\Users\V\Documents\_PROGRAMS_\"

 windowStyle = 1
 waitUntilFinished = True
 oshell.run "python table.py", windowStyle, waitUntilFinished
 xl.Application.Quit
```

I don't think adding the python program is important since that isn't really the problem. Although I will say that I tried putting a delay in the python program to see if that would change anything (it didn't).

I though adding the two extra arguments to .run would make it wait until the process is finished but I guess I must be missing something?

I'm just starting to learn how to use vbscript so any explanations of code would be welcomed!

Thanks!

EDIT: So after more testing it seems that it does have something to do with accessing the excel document, as just printing 'Hello World' to a file did actually work and the file was created (I made it in the wrong directory by accident so I was looking in the wrong place). But trying it with the data from the excel document no file is created, the program just ends

So here's the python code I wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/python27
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_excel("TEST.xlsx") #Get excel doc

file = open("text.txt", "w") #Open new file
file.write(table.columns.values) #Print out column headers
file.write("Hello!")
file.close()
```

Comment: You may be using wscript where cscript is required. The former is GUI windowed, the latter is a command window interface.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look into it!

Comment: @ThatOneCanadian You've changed `CurrentDirectory`. As a child process, python command line interpreter (python.exe) inherits **[*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683463(v=vs.85).aspx)** current working directory from its parent (wscript.exe or cscript.exe) and looks for `table.py` in `C:\Users\V\Documents\_PROGRAMS_`. That must be the issue if `table.py` is not there. Python can't open your script to run.

Comment: Ah that's the thing though, table.py IS in the same directory (`C:\Users\V\Documents\_PROGRAMS_`) and if I change the code so that it doesn't access the workbook the text file is created and it works fine. It's just that for whatever reason once I try and read the excel workbook my program just seems to skip over creating the text file and ends the program